# Monitoring eth0 using libudev in Qt wrapper class

Tags: linux, qt, udev

I need to display the status of the ethernet connection (eth0) on the GUI, i.e. is the link up or not.
I have a Davicom DM9000 PHY.

I know there are various ways to skin this cat, like parsing ifconfig, polling /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate, etc.

However, as I will need to monitor other devices also, like USB, I would like to use libudev for this as a more generic implementation. 
Furthermore, I would like to use the monitor mechanism (using a select() ) and in doing so prevent having to poll.
I have wrapped the libudev functionality in a Qt class and intend on using signal/slot mechanisms to indicate events to my program.

Problem is, I can't seem to generate UDEV events from eth0 no matter what.
I have also tried using

```
udevadm monitor
```

but no events either when unplugging my ethernet cable.

I don't think my code is too far off, because I am able to generate events for USB (hidraw) devices by unplugging my keyboard, for example.
Also, I am able to see eth0's attributes using the libudev enumerate mechanism (but this is a polling process)

My question - is this possible, i.e. to use libudev's udev_monitor functions to catch events on eth0?

Sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 0):

Have already looked at [D-bus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/)? Via D-Bus and underlying services you can get all the info you need. See this a little bit outdated [article](http://www.linux.com/news/hardware/peripherals/180950-udev) to understand the concept. See [Qt/D-Bus documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtdbus-index.html).